# Textarea doesn't work within itself

Tags: html, css, web

I have a textarea. When I click inside it at the top it doesn't focus, but when I click lower down it does.

```
<textarea type="text" value="" id="theMessage" required></textarea>

textarea {
 width: 485px;
 height: 310px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 110px;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 resize: none;
 font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: change position absolute to position:relative. You are pointing an absolute element that (in the zone you can't focus it) there are some other element over it. Check that is true, when you set position relative, the textarea will moove a bit lower and it will be focusable on all textarea parts. Then inspect which element are over the non-clickeable part of textarea (that causes your issue)

Answer (score 0):

```css
textarea {
 width: 485px;
 height: 310px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 110px;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 resize: none;
 font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
 border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<textarea type="text" value="" id="theMessage" required></textarea>
```

```
<textarea type="text" value="" id="theMessage" required></textarea>
<style>
textarea {
 width: 485px;
 height: 310px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 110px;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 resize: none;
 font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
 border:2px solid black;
}</style>
```

you can make the position relative or set border to text-area to make it visible.In code show above is set `border:2px solid black;`
you can set and a background color to make it more visible.

```
background:white;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be that some other div overlapping you `textarea` because of `absolute` position.

Here is the example that demonstrates how this could happen: `div.overlap` is placed above your textarea, because `absolute` position removes texterea from normal document flow.

```
<textarea type="text" value="" id="theMessage" required></textarea>

<div class="overlap"></div>

textarea {
 width: 485px;
 height: 310px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 110px;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 resize: none;
 font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.overlap {
  height: 200px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h1aLf94x/4/

So check your document for any elements that can overlap over textarea, and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a div element which is overlapping the textarea element. Remove the position attribute from the styling and you can see your textarea able to be clicked.